# How can I pass user input from an HTML form to an arcpy script?

Tags: arcpy, leaflet, javascript, html

I currently have an arcpy script that selects stores that are open after the user inputs their date and time. I'm looking to embed the results on a website using leaflet. If I have the user input their date and time using an HTML form, how can I pass the results to my arcpy script?

Comment: you will need a webserver with cgi or wsgi to pass html forms to python scripts.

Comment: I think you need to investigate the term geoprocessing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should look at either some sort of RESTful service via a [WSGI server](https://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html) or a [Geoprocessing Service](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/what-is-a-geoprocessing-service-.htm), which the latter requires ArcGIS Server.

If you don't have access to ArcGIS Server, I strongly recommend using WSGI server such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), or a handful of other options.

A colleague and I presented [this sample mabpox based application](https://github.com/Bolton-and-Menk-GIS/Python_WebServices_GISLIS_2017) that calls on a Python Flask service (see the `flask_sample` folder). This is a fairly simple example of a custom REST service from a WSGI service.  You can run the server locally or for production it is recommended to deploy on [IIS](http://netdot.co/2015/03/09/flask-on-iis/) or Apache.